# Find the max and min values of function with using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

$\mathbf{f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3}$ constraint to **x+y+z=4** find max and min values of function. Oh k. I find λ as 16/3. $\mathbf{∇f=(3x^2 , 3y^2 , 3z^2)}$ and **∇g= as (1,1,1)** so $3x^2$ must be equal to λ so $x= \sqrt{λ/3}$ and I typed at constraint for finding λ  then I got λ as $-16/3$ and $16/3$ but function leads me to a complex value like $\mathbf{f(x,y,z)=-i 64/3}$ where is my fault? And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: What happens with $f(t,4-t,0)$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Similarly, consider $f(t,t,4-2t)$.

Comment: what if it dne?

Comment: There is no global $\max$ or $\min$ (that is you can find points for which $f$ has arbitrarily large or small values). So you need to investigate what the solutions of the Lagrange multiplier equations give you.

Comment: The Lagrange equations just give you $|x|=|y|=|z|$ (and $x+y+z=4$ of course).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it